# BigQuery http post request Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-bigquery

I'm having real trouble sending any data to BigQuery via http request, set up the necessary service account for credentials but the request is getting me nowhere.

pretty new to coding and there is sparse documentation out there for anyone at my level.

I am firmly down the rabbit hole with this one.

```
  void sendBQData() {
http.post(
    'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets/datasetId/tables/tableId/insertAll',
    body: {
      'kind': TableDataInsertAllRequest,
      'rows': [
        {
          'json': {'test1': 'Tester String'},
        }
      ]
    });
```

}

Comment: Define "getting me nowhere", what exactly is happening? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: Getting no errors at all, haven't tried running a debugger I'm that new but will look into that. Just thought it may be something obvious to someone.

Comment: Could you elaborate more in the issue you are facing  and what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: All I'm trying to achieve is to stream data into BigQuery